# Boolean type soap request ignored by .net client

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I tried to call a webservices method through my asp.net project.

I used Fiddler to log the soap request. However, I found a boolean type value in the request was not sent, the other types work fine.

The xsd file is defined like:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestObject">
 <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
  <xs:extension base="com:TestObjectDTO">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="scenario" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="asap" type="xs:boolean" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

The soap request was logged as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <TestObjectDTO xsi:type="TestObject" xmlns="http://ws.com/service/">
     <scenario>scenario_1</scenario>
    </TestObjectDTO>
</soap:Body>
```

The asap element was missing. Any idea?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="asap" type="xs:boolean" />
```

**minOccurs="0"** means it's optional, and doesn't need to appear in the request. With no default specified, I'd assume it'll default to false, or it might have to be represented by a nullable type.

Comment: It makes sense. But how to fix it? I can not use optional argument in .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this and it looks like .NET generates two fields for you to modify

.asap
  .asapSpecified

When we set both to true, it worked